# Having trouble with the sum function

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sum

I am making a student database which contain the course id, course name, credits of each course, pass fail statement and the grades. Now I want to get the sum of the grades in a button and make them appear on a textbox. this is the code I wrote, but it's giving me an error saying the sum function doesn't exist. What should I do?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";
   string Query = " Select sum (grade) form studentdata.semestre1";
   MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
   MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, ConDatabase);
   MySqlDataReader myReader;
    ConDatabase.Open();
    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader() ;
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        textBox2.Text = myReader.GetString(0);
    }
    myReader.Close();
```

Comment: Check your query, you misspelled `FROM`

Answer (score 2):

**Two reasons:**

1. SQL query should not have space between the function and the column name
2. Change your query from "Form" to "FROM"

   ```
   string Query = "Select SUM(grade) FROM studentdata.semestre1";
   ```

Comment: @Typist: They are not. Where did you get that?

Comment: This should be upvoted for giving reason on sum function with space. Yes, it is not allowed, on any function.

Comment: @juergend, When you click, down arrow in-front of the answer, a popup will appear.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Why did you change your answer? Explain again why `'sum (grade)'` is not correct but `'sum(grade)'`.

Comment: @Ravinder Sorry, since i got down vote i have changed my answer! will update it

Comment: string Querry = "Select SUM(grade)/SUM(credits)  FROM studentdata.semestre1";

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 SELECT SUM(grade) FROM studentdata.semestre1
```

The most important change is the `from`.

For a more complete fix; add `using`, and use `ExecuteScalar` here:

```
using(MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT SUM(grade) FROM studentdata.semestre1", ConDatabase))
{
    ConDatabase.Open();
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: thank you :) now i want to get the average of the grades which is this sum / sum1 ( with sum1 = the sum of credits) how could i do this ?

Comment: @user3731064 would `AVG` suffice? Or do you mean `SUM(grade) / SUM(credits)` ?

Comment: AVG is what i want to do so any help ? isn't it the same as sum(grade) / sum(credits)?

Comment: @user3731064 no, `AVG` is `SUM/COUNT`

Comment: would you tell me how to do both of them or the sum (grades ) / sum (credits) only cz this is what i rly need

Comment: @guetty depending on where `credits` is, it could be exactly as shown already

Comment: i've done the exact same thing : created a new Querry2 String and new cmddatabase1 and myreader1 , then wrote while ((myReader.Read()) && (myReader1.Read()))
            {
                textBox2.Text =Convert.ToString(double.Parse( myReader.GetString(0))/ double.Parse(myReader1.GetString(0))) ;
            }
            myReader.Close();
            myReader1.Close();

Comment: but when executing the program and clicking on the average button an error appeared which is : **there is already an opened Data Reader which is associated with this Connection which must be closed first** do you know what should i do ?